# Selecting by second level key from multidimensional HTML name array using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select all the inputs with name like `pref[*][location][]` using jQuery selector or Javascript? I am interested in getting it by the second level key 'location'.

```
<input type="text" name="pref[1][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][location][]" value="get_this">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][location][]" value="get_this_too">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][other]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[2][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[2][location][]" value="get_this_too">
<input type="text" name="pref[2][location][]" value="get_this_too">
<input type="text" name="pref[3][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[3][other]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="location" value="no">
```

Comment: Why not use a class on these input to make it more simpler ? Or is it something you do not have access to ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I see the point. There is an existing implementation where I have to add an extra dimension of input, so I thought changing the selectors would be simpler.

Comment: So you want to grab the input and then change/replace the selector ? Not sure whats the end goal here

Comment: The code I am modifying is using jQuery selectors like `$('input[name="pref[location][]"]')` , so I thought changing the selectors would be the shortest path. The goal here is still grabbing the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to get all the `inputs` you have and then `filter` them out using their `name` attribute.

To get the all `input` by second level key `[location]` we can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method and that way we will get the inputs `containing` that `key` only.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('input').each(function(i, el) {
  if ($(el).attr('name').includes('[location]')) {
    console.log(el)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="pref[1][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][location][]" value="get_this">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][location][]" value="get_this_too">
<input type="text" name="pref[1][other]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[2][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[2][location][]" value="get_this_too">
<input type="text" name="pref[2][location][]" value="get_this_too">
<input type="text" name="pref[3][term][]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="pref[3][other]" value="no">
<input type="text" name="location" value="no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` as @AlwaysHelping suggested:

```
$('input[name^="pref"]').filter('[name*="location"]')
```

Or match the name attributes from the ending part, a bit hacky though.

```
$('input[name$="[location][]"]')
```